# javascriptのFileListから、指定要素を削除したいです

Tags: javascript, html5

現在は下記のような実装になっており、elseに入ったらその時点のfile[i]を削除したいのですが方法が分かりません。ご教授をお願いします。

```js
var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length;i++){
            if (files[i].type == 'video/3gpp' || files[i].type == 'video/3gpp2' ||
            files[i].type == 'audio/vnd.dlna.adts' || files[i].type == 'video/avi' ||
            files[i].type == 'video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts' || files[i].type == 'audio/x-m4a' ||
            files[i].type == 'audio/x-m4b' || files[i].type == 'audio/x-m4p' ||
            files[i].type == 'video/quicktime' || files[i].type == 'video/mp4' ||
            files[i].type == 'audio/wav' || files[i].type == 'video/x-matroska' ||
            files[i].type == 'audio/x-matroska' || files[i].type == 'audio/mp3') {
                alert(files[i].type + 'ファイルが選択されました');
            }
            else {
                alert(files[i].type + '不正なファイル形式です');
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結果を保存する配列を用意して、そこに必要な物だけ保存するのはどうでしょうか？
説明のためにファイルの配列ではなく単なる文字列の配列で書いてみました。
また条件判断もスッキリ書けるように書きなおしました。

```
files = ['video/3gpp', 'audio/x-m4b', 'other'];
accepted_file_types = [
    'video/3gpp','video/3gpp2','audio/vnd.dlna.adts', 'video/avi', 'audio/x-m4b'
];
filtered_files = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    if(accepted_file_types.indexOf(files[i]) >= 0){
        filtered_files.push(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
上記を参考に実装したところ、解決することが出来ました。
また、ソースもきれいに纏めることが出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

配列の中から、条件に合ったものだけを抽出するには、
Array.prototype.filter関数が使えます。

```js
// すべてのファイル
var files = [
  {file_name: "testA", type: "a"},
  {file_name: "testB", type: "b"},
  {file_name: "testC", type: "c"},
  {file_name: "testD", type: "d"},
  {file_name: "testE", type: "a"},
  {file_name: "testF", type: "b"},
];

// 許可するファイルタイプ
var accepted_types = ["a", "c"];

// フィルタリング
var filtered_files = files.filter(function(file){
  return accepted_types.indexOf(file.type) >= 0;
  });

// 結果表示
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML=JSON.stringify(filtered_files);
```

Answer (score 0):

`splice()`を使えば削除できます。

```
if(...){
    // 省略
}else{
    files.splice(i, 1);
}
```

**追記：**
0からの要素アクセスでは`splice`した際に正しい位置を保持できないため、逆からのアクセスに修正。

```js
    var files = [
        {"type" : "aaa"},
        {"type" : "bbb"},
        {"type" : "ccc"},
        {"type" : "ddd"},
        {"type" : "eee"}
    ];
    
    for(var i = files.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(i==0 || i==2 || i==4){
            // 配列要素の削除
            files.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        $('#target').append(files[i].type+'<br />');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: for ループ内で 配列自体を `splice` で変更してしまうとその時点で配列の長さが変更され for 分が最後までい実行されません。例えば`files = ['video/3gpp', 'audio/x-m4b', 'other', 'other2'];`で処理を行うと `other`は除外されますが `other2`が残ってしまいます。
こちらによると`while (i--)` で処理して回避する場合には問題ないようです。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Comment: @ironsand あれ？私もそう思ったんで試してみたんです。それで問題なかったんですけど何か条件があるんでしょうか。

Comment: どんなサンプルで試されました？ 私はこれで確認しました。 http://repl.it/eH5

Comment: @ironsand 私が追記したサンプルでも配列が正しく削除されているように見えるのですが･･･

Comment: それだと、条件が `i==2 || i==3` の場合に `ddd` が削除されないんですよ。 http://repl.it/eH5/

Comment: @ironsand あぁ、分かりました。上記の書き方では条件が一つしかないのでたまたま上手く行っているだけですね。複数条件にすると正しく動作しませんでした。

Comment: 正常に動作するように修正しました。

Comment: 降順なら `i = files.length-1; i >= 0` で動きますね。

Comment: @ironsand 指摘ありがとうございます。そうですね、一つ減じる必要がありますね。。

Comment: @ironsand 必要なのは`i >= 0`だけでした。ちょっと動きが分からないのでもう少し見てみます。

Comment: 配列サイズを越えてるのでループ内で `files[i]` すると予期せぬ動作になります。

Comment: @ironsand 仰るとおりですね。どれが削除されなければいけないか勘違いしていました。お手数おかけしました。